# Field calculation using Python Parser

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I have a table as like below:

[image]

I want to generate python script to calculate the value Low, Medium and High into a single layer.

I tried using this script:

```
Parser:
Python

Expression:
Reclass( Flood_Severity )

Code Block:
def Reclass ( Flood_Severity ):
    if ( FAT = 1 and FV = 1 and FD < 3):
        return "Low"
    elif ( FAT = 1 and FV = 1 and FD >= 3):
        return "Medium"
    elif ( FAT = 1 and FV = 2 and FD = 1):
        return "Low"
    elif ( FAT = 1 and FV = 2 and FD > 1 and FD < 4):
        return "Medium"
    elif ( FAT = 1 and FV = 2 and FD=4):
        return "High"
```

But it failed.
May I know how to fix the script?

Comment: Failed how? Do you get errors? Your table cant look like that in ArcMap, can you add a screenshot showing the attribute table

Comment: I agree with @BERA you need to edit your question and include an image of your data as it is in ArcMap.

Comment: Table shown cannot be analyzed. It looks like result of normal flat database table pivoted in Excel or similar.

Answer (score 3):

You are going to get errors for using **=** as a comparison operator , it should be two **==**.

See: [Python Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp)

And you need to include all the fields you use in the function, when declaring and calling it:

```
def Reclass ( FAT, FV, FD ):
   ...
```

And when you call it:

```
Reclass( !FAT!, !FV!, !FD! )
```